# How do triple lists works in Ionic and Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this response JSON and I am trying to display this list from list. But Ionic doesn't work as expected. How can I display this data correctly in ionic with angular?

```json
{
    "secciones": {
        "FUTBOL SALA": {
                "SENIOR":[
                    {"codEquipo": "FSSENA", "nombre": "NOMBREEQUIPO", "seccion": "FUTBOL SALA", "categoria": "SENIOR",…}
                ],
                "BENJAMÍN":[
                    {"codEquipo": "FSBENJA", "nombre": "NOMBREEQUIPO", "seccion": "FUTBOL SALA", "categoria": "BENJAMÍN",…}
                ]
            },
            "BALONCESTO": {
                "ALEVÍN": [
                    {"codEquipo": "BALALEB", "nombre": "NOMBREEQUIPO", "seccion": "BALONCESTO", "categoria": "ALEVÍN",…}
                ],
                "CADETE": [
                    {"codEquipo": "BALCAD", "nombre": "NOMBREEQUIPO", "seccion": "BALONCESTO", "categoria": "CADETE",…}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let seccion of equipos | keyvalue">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let categoria of seccion.value | keyvalue">
                <ion-label>{{categoria.key}}</ion-label>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of categoria.value | keyvalue">
                        <ion-label>{{item.key}}</ion-label>
                        <ion-list>
                            <ion-item *ngFor="let equipo of item.value">
                                <ion-label>{{equipo.nombre}}</ion-label>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The json you have posted is not valid. Please update.

Comment: What do you mean by `Ionic doesn't work as expected` ? What is the expected result and what is the actual result ? Why is there `seccion of equipos` in your html and there is not `equipos` in your json ?

Comment: @E.Maggini The json posted is certainly an example, if you remove the `...` it is valid.

Comment: @marco as posted it is not valid and also implies there is data missing to help solve this issue.. In fact, you question "why is there no equipos" reflects such.